# Adding .mobileprovision to XCode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have recently upgraded the XCode to 6.1.1 version. After upgrading I am not able to create Archieve. It asks me to import Developer Profile. I have downloaded the profile from member center. Please help me in importing the same to XCode. When I navigate to the folder where the Profile is present,I am not able to select the same to add in XCode.

Thank you...!

I am getting the below pop up when I try to create archive. I tried downloading the Provisioning Profile from member center but it dint solve the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU3oi.png

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the existing certificate from member center did not resolve the issue. Problem is resolved when I requested a new certificate and installed it in the Mac. I think we have to request a new "App Store and Ad Hoc" Certificate for XCode 6.1.1[image]